# Google scripts. TypeError: Cannot call method "replace" of undefined

Tags: javascript

First post please go easy on me.

I have an array that looks something like this `[BTC-LTC, BTC-DOGE, BTC-VTC]` I am trying to change all the "-" with "_". But am having trouble with using the `.replace()` method. Here is my code.

```
var array = [BTC-LTC, BTC-DOGE, BTC-VTC];    
var fixedArray = [];

for(var i=0; i <= array.length; i++){
   var str = JSON.stringify(array[i]);
   var res = str.replace("-","_");
   fixedArray.push(res);
};
```

I tried without using the `JSON.stringify` but that didn't work either. I have also tried to first create `var str = String();` this also did not work. Is it possible that the method `.replace()` is not available in google scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `var array = [BTC-LTC, BTC-DOGE, BTC-VTC];`

should be

`var array = ["BTC-LTC", "BTC-DOGE", "BTC-VTC"];`

However I gather from the comments that this is just a typo in your initial example.

`var str = JSON.stringify(array[i]);` is  redundant. You can just do `var str = array[i];` Since the value in the array is already a string, there's no need to turn it into one again - the "stringify" method expects to be given an object or array to work on.

However the main problem is that your `for` loop goes on one too many iterations. Arrays are zero-based, so you need to stop looping when the index is 1 *less than* the length of the array, not *equal to* it. e.g. if array.length is 10 then there are 10 indices, but they start at 0, so the indices are 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. If your loop goes on to equal to array.length, then on the last loop `array[10]` will be out of bounds, and it's only this last iteration which is giving you the `undefined` error.

```
var array = ["BTC-LTC", "BTC-DOGE", "BTC-VTC"];
var fixedArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   var str = array[i];
   var res = str.replace("-","_");
   fixedArray.push(res);
}
```

Comment: Okay so i tried to change my array of variables to an array of strings. so that i could use the for loop as planed. but now if I try `array.map(String);` the array is not converting the variables to strings. In the `array.map(String);` the word string is not turning blue.

Comment: where does array.map come into it? You never mentioned this. What are you trying to do and at what point in the process?

Comment: I am pulling the array out of a website api.  When I look at the return of  the api all the elements are already in string format. not sure why my a array has variables and not strings in it.

Comment: I can't really give you an answer to that without seeing the path you take from the API data to the `for` loop you've given here. Clearly the example in your question is not entirely the real-world scenario, and there's something elsewhere going wrong perhaps.

Comment: ` var urlBit = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarkets";`
`  var responseAPIbittrex = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlBit);`
`  var bittrexData =JSON.parse(responseAPIbittrex).result;  
` var bittrexPairs = bittrexData.map(function(a) {return a.MarketName;});  `
`var strArr = bittrexPairs.map(function(e){return e.toString()});`
 keep in mind this is in google scripts

Comment: what do you mean by "this is in google scripts"? This is _your_ code that you're describing here, I assume. P.S. you can edit comments for 5 minutes. The issue is spaces just after your backticks.

Comment: in order for me to see what the problem is with this, I need to know what the content of `urlBit` is after the first line is run.

Comment: I'm trying to put my final info on a google sheet and and using the google scripts editor. (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/)

Comment: the value of `strArray` in that example is an array of strings which you should be able to feed into the `for` loop in my sample. You shouldn't need to manipulate it any further.

Comment: OK so I just found the real problem. Your typo in the initial example using objects instead of strings was a red herring. The real problem is that your for loop goes on too long. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you're trying to edit **strings**, not **variables**, so you need quotes in your array, and a `g` in your `replace` in case you have multiple things to replace :

```
var array = ['BTC-LTC', 'BTC-DOGE', 'BTC-VTC'];    
var fixedArray = [];

for(var i=0; i <= array.length; i++){
   fixedArray.push(array[i].replace(/-/g, '_'));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

code is working fine if we change as below:

```
var array = ['BTC-LTC', 'BTC-DOGE', 'BTC-VTC'];
```